# QT copy to QTemporaryFile

Tags: c++, qt, temporary-files

I'd like to make a copy of `some/path/myfile` in `$TMPDIR/myprog-<random-string>.ext`, such that I can then pass it on to a 3rd party procedure that chokes on extensionless files.

Here's what I'd like to work:

```
QString originalPath = "some/path/myfile";

QTemporaryFile f(
    QDir::temp().absoluteFilePath("mprog-XXXXXX.ext")
);

// f.open(); ?

QFile(originalPath).copy(f.fileName());
```

However, I now have a problem - either the file doesn't yet exist, and thus hasn't been assigned a temporary `fileName()`, or the file name has been assigned but the file itself already exists, preventing the new file being copied on top.

How can I copy a file to a temporary location in QT, and have the temporary copy removed when the destructor of QTemporaryFile is called?

Answer (score 2):

If the file doesn't exist, create the `QTemporaryFile` object exactly as you have done, open it and then close it immediately. This will generate the random filename and create it on the disk.

When your `QTemporaryFile` object gets destroyed, the file will be deleted from the disk.

Comment: At the point that it exists on disk, `.copy(` will refuse to make the copy and overwrite it

Comment: From docs: "Note that if a file with the name newName already exists, copy() returns false..."

Comment: Also from the docs: "The name of the temporary file is guaranteed to be unique (i.e., you are guaranteed to not overwrite an existing file), and the file will subsequently be removed upon destruction of the QTemporaryFile object"

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Qt (5.3) doesn't support copying to an existing file. The only correct, race-free use of `QTemporaryFile` is to `open()` it, creating it in the process, and then operate on it.

You'll need to implement the copy yourself, I'm afraid :(

On Windows, if you expect there to be some gain from using `CopyFileEx`, I have [a complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19150462/1329652) that wraps it for Qt's perusal, with progress signals.

The real question is: do you really need to create a copy? Wouldn't a hard link do? Since Qt runs, for the most part, on Unices and Windows, you can create a symbolic link wrapper that will wrap POSIX `link()` and winapi [`CreateHardLink`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363860(v=vs.85).aspx). If hard link creation fails, or the temporary folder is on a different volume, you can then try [`CreateSymbolicLink`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363866(v=vs.85).aspx). Of course you'd need to look up `CreateSymbolicLinkW` using `QLibrary` if you intend your executable to start un XP at all. If that fails, you're either running on XP or on a FAT partition, and the final fallback is copying.

Would it be out of the question to rename the file, run the 3rd-party application on it, then rename it back?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not going to be actually using the file / stream to the file QTemporaryFile created for you, you're better off using QUuid instead to just generate a guaranteed unique filename. This generates a unique filename, roughly equivalent to QTemporaryFile:

```
QUuid uuid = QUuid::createUuid();
QString tempFileFullPath = QDir::toNativeSeparators(QDir::tempPath() + "/" + qApp->applicationName().replace(" ", "") + "_" + uuid.toString(QUuid::WithoutBraces) + ".dat");
```

I like the temporary filename to not contain spaces, so I removed that from the app name used for the filename prefix. (You should call QApplication::setApplicationName in your main() function so this will work.)

Also, you should probably change the .dat extension to something suitable for your file type.