# QT - QFile copy operation extremely slow

Tags: c++, qt, qfile

I'm developing an application that needs to copy lots of files from one folder to another, using **QT (5.6.1)**

For doing this, I've been using the `QFile::copy()` method. This works well, except for one thing: it is **extremely** slow. Takes more than twice the time that the same copy operation takes using windows explorer.

Wondering why this was, I dug into the QT source code, and I found this in `qfile.cpp`, which looks relevant:

```
char block[4096];
qint64 totalRead = 0;
while(!atEnd()) {
    qint64 in = read(block, sizeof(block));
    if (in <= 0)
        break;
    totalRead += in;
    if(in != out.write(block, in)) {
        close();
        d->setError(QFile::CopyError, tr("Failure to write block"));
        error = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

So, from what I understand, the copy operation is using a 4096-byte buffer. This is very small for a copy operation, and could well be the cause of the issue.
So what I did was change the size of the buffer to:

```
char block[4194304]; // 4MB buffer
```

Then I rebuilt the entire QT library to include this change. However, all the modification did was break the method completely. Now when my application tries to invoke QFile::Copy() the operation gets interrupted immediately (method doesn't even start to run, stops before the first line according to QtCreator's debugger). The debugger tells me:

```
The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the Operating System.

Signal name :
SIGSEGV
Signal meaning :
Segmentation fault
```

My c++ is a bit rusty, but I don't understand how just changing the allocation size of an array can completely break a method... can anyone help by either:

1) Telling me why QFile:Copy() is so slow (am I missing something? It's not just on my PC, tested on several different machines). And is the coulprit actually the code I posted above or something else entirely?
2) Telling me why that one change completely breaks QFile

Comment: There's a benchmark in qtbase (`tests/benchmarks/corelib/io/qfile`), which tries to read a file on Win32 using different block sizes. I'm not sure why 4K was universally selected. Perhaps it depends on the hard disk technology? Could you try running the benchmark (`readBigFile_Win32` test function) and check?

Comment: On Windows, your best bet will be to use CopyFileEx, see [this complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19136936/1329652) with progress indication :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, changing the buffer size did no good, since that apparently is just a fallback in case the derived function `engine()->copy()` fails. I don't know exactly how that function works, nor did I want to waste time modifying core QT engine classes to make this work.

In the end, since my project was only supposed to run on Windows, I ended up using the native Win32 copy function. So I replaced my call to:

```
QFile::copy(src, dest);
```

with:

```
CopyFileExW((LPCWSTR)src.utf16(), (LPCWSTR)dest.utf16(), 0, this, 0, 0);
```

Note that you must `#include "windows.h"` for this invocation to work.

Comment: Have a look at my answer as well. It seems that with newer versions of `Qt` framework `QFile::copy()` is as fast as the native implementation.

Answer (score 7):

The reason that your change broke QFile is that a 4M buffer won't fit on the stack (the default stack size is typically something like 1M).  A quick fix would be:

```
std::vector<char> vec(4*1024*1024);
char *block = &vec.front();
```

The vector will allocate the big buffer on the heap (and take care of deallocating when you are done), and you just point `block` at the front of the vector.

I think your analysis of why copy is slow is spot on.

Comment: Thanks, I had thought of that but I didn't think the stack was actually so small, will try as soon as the QT source rebuilds. Could take a while :)
As for the reason: it MIGHT be, but I also noticed that that code only runs if the "d->engine()->copy(newName)" fails. Will need to check this too.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be no more an issue with newer version of Qt (I am using 5.9.2). Please have a look at `QFileSystemEngine::copyFile()` in https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/io/qfilesystemengine_win.cpp.html The code uses native function `CopyFile2`. Also my testing confirmed that `QFile::copy()` is on par with the native implementation on Windows. Seems Qt has made some progress in this area.