# File Copy Disable Buffering with Qt

Tags: qt, file, winapi

I am writing a file replicator data backup software using the Qt framework and am experiencing a 'flaw' in the data copying.

If I copy data from an SSD to a HDD the SSD is much faster to read data than the HDD is to write data. Because of this the data that is read fills a buffer before it is written to the HDD.

This wouldn't be a problem except that the progress meter for data copy stalls when the buffer gets filled then when it gets emptied it races to get filled again. So the progress meter indicates a bunch of progress, then it stalls, then it indicates progress, then stalls, etc. It looks pretty ugly compared to constant progress which happens when data is written at a constant rate.

Is there a way around this with Qt? I tried using `QFile::flush()` but it didn't help.

We have `FlushFileBuffers` from Win32 api but the documentation says it's inefficient when used after every write to a disk drive device when many writes are being performed separately.

We can call the `CreateFile` function with the `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` and `FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH` flags but is there a way to do this with `QFile`'s?

And then we have the option of completely turning off caching for the target disk as [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winsdk/2009/10/09/enable-or-disable-enable-write-caching-on-disk-behavior-on-disk/).

What would be the most elegant solution?

Here's the relevant code:

```
QFile sourceFile;
QFile targetTempFile;
// ...
QByteArray buffer;
for (int count = 0; !(buffer = sourceFile.read(1000000)).isEmpty() && cancel == false; count++)
{
    int readSize = buffer.size();
    targetTempFile.write(buffer);
    //targetTempFile.flush();
    setProgressMeters(readSize, fileSize, jobSize);
    setTimeLabels(startTime.elapsed(),readSize);
}
```

Comment: @JoshOrenberg The `A` and `W` suffixes on winapi functions have to do with `char` vs. `wchar_t` interfaces. The modern default is to alias `ApiW` to `Api`, i.e. `CopyFileEx` is same as `CopyFileExW`.

Comment: What about that CopyFile2 - is it just a CopyFileEx with a different structure for parameters?

Answer (score 0):

For performant file copying on Windows, you should use `CopyFileEx`, not `QFile`. `CopyFileEx` will use lower level APIs that may result in zero-copy copying on modern hardware. See [this example of `CopyFileEx` integration with Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19136936/copyfileex-with-progress-callback-in-qt/19150462#19150462).

To obtain a native `HANDLE` from a `QFileDevice` (i.e. `QFile`/`QSaveFile`), and to use `ReOpenFile` on a `QFile`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50191480/1329652).

Comment: How would one modify the CopyFileEx example to be thread-safe if run from a worker object moved to a worker thread via a worker->moveToThread(workerThread); call?

Comment: @JoshOrenberg That question doesn't belong here - ask in the place where you want to see the modifications. But in general, the `Copier`  is inherently thread-safe because it uses a worker thread internally anyway - c.f. `QtConcurrent::run`. There's no point to moving `Copier` to any other thread.