# How to convert DWORD to LPPROGRESS_ROUTINE callback for CopyFileExW?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, file-copying

This is part of an application aimed at handling files & backups. My aim is to implement this function to allow the system to copy files faster.

I came across this very useful [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19150462/4628115) on SO suggesting how to implement the [CopyFileExW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-copyfileexw) / [CopyFile2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-copyfile2) in Qt.

**The problem**

using the [code as posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19150462/4628115) runs perfectly, however attempting to modify it to fit into my application causes the following problem:

```
path\to\project\...\libs\backupmanager.cpp:2806: error: cannot convert 'DWORD (BackupManager::*)(LARGE_INTEGER, LARGE_INTEGER, LARGE_INTEGER, LARGE_INTEGER, DWORD, DWORD, HANDLE, HANDLE, LPVOID) {aka long unsigned int (BackupManager::*)(_LARGE_INTEGER, _LARGE_INTEGER, _LARGE_INTEGER, _LARGE_INTEGER, long unsigned int, long unsigned int, void*, void*, void*)}' to 'LPPROGRESS_ROUTINE {aka long unsigned int (__attribute__((__stdcall__)) *)(_LARGE_INTEGER, _LARGE_INTEGER, _LARGE_INTEGER, _LARGE_INTEGER, long unsigned int, long unsigned int, void*, void*, void*)}' for argument '3' to 'WINBOOL CopyFileExW(LPCWSTR, LPCWSTR, LPPROGRESS_ROUTINE, LPVOID, LPBOOL, DWORD)'
                            &BackupManager::copyProgress, this, &bStopBackup, 0);
                                                                           ^
```

I did not see any mention of a requirement for the `LPPROGRESS_ROUTINE` callback to be `static`, but I changed it to static (and commented out those offending lines), yet this problem persists (which I almost expected).

It appears the signatures match according, where `DWORD === unsigned int`, `LPVOID & HANDLE === *void` and where [LPPROGRESS_ROUTINE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nc-winbase-lpprogress_routine) suggests its definition can return a `DWORD`.

> LPPROGRESS_ROUTINE LpprogressRoutine;
>
> DWORD LpprogressRoutine(   LARGE_INTEGER TotalFileSize,
> LARGE_INTEGER TotalBytesTransferred,   LARGE_INTEGER StreamSize,
> LARGE_INTEGER StreamBytesTransferred,   DWORD dwStreamNumber,   DWORD
> dwCallbackReason,   HANDLE hSourceFile,   HANDLE hDestinationFile,
> LPVOID lpData ) {...}

How can I resolve this as I have absolutely no idea?

---

**Summary of change(s):**

- changed to non-static method

```
DWORD CALLBACK copyProgress(
      LARGE_INTEGER totalSize, LARGE_INTEGER totalTransferred,
      LARGE_INTEGER streamSize, LARGE_INTEGER streamTransferred,
      DWORD streamNo, DWORD callbackReason, HANDLE src, HANDLE dst,
      LPVOID data);
```

- header change of copy method

```
void copyFile(QString m_src, QString m_dst);
```

**Full (minimal) Code below:**

```
class BackupManager : public QObject {
     Q_OBJECT

 private:
 QWaitCondition pauseThreadCondition;
 QMutex backupPauseLock;
 bool bPauseBackup = false, bStopBackup = false;

 static DWORD CALLBACK copyProgress(
      LARGE_INTEGER totalSize, LARGE_INTEGER totalTransferred,
      LARGE_INTEGER streamSize, LARGE_INTEGER streamTransferred,
      DWORD streamNo, DWORD callbackReason, HANDLE src, HANDLE dst,
      LPVOID data);

     void copyFile(QString m_src, QString m_dst);

  //...

  signals:
     void fileCopyFinished();
     void fileCopyFailed(QString error);
     void fileCopyProgress(qint64 progress, qint64 total);
  //...
}
```

**and source**

```
void BackupManager::copyFile(QString m_src, QString m_dst)
{
     auto rc = CopyFileExW((LPCWSTR)m_src.utf16(), (LPCWSTR)m_dst.utf16(),
                           &BackupManager::copyProgress, this, &bStopBackup, 0);
     if (!rc)
          emit fileCopyFailed(getLastErrorMsg());
     emit fileCopyFinished();
}
DWORD CALLBACK BackupManager::copyProgress(
     const LARGE_INTEGER totalSize, const LARGE_INTEGER totalTransferred,
     LARGE_INTEGER, LARGE_INTEGER, DWORD,
     DWORD, HANDLE, HANDLE,
     LPVOID data)
{
     emit fileCopyProgress(totalTransferred.QuadPart, totalSize.QuadPart);
     if (bPauseBackup) {
          backupPauseLock.lock();
          pauseThreadCondition.wait(&backupPauseLock);
          backupPauseLock.unlock();
     }
     return PROGRESS_CONTINUE;
}
```

Image (if it helps at all)

[image]

---

**UPDATE**

As per @[RbMm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6401656/rbmm)'s request, see below for 'static' impl and corresponding error.

Qt Compile Error:

```
path\to\project\...\libs\backupmanager.cpp:2806: error: cannot convert 'bool*' to 'LPBOOL {aka int*}' for argument '5' to 'WINBOOL CopyFileExW(LPCWSTR, LPCWSTR, LPPROGRESS_ROUTINE, LPVOID, LPBOOL, DWORD)'
                            &BackupManager::copyProgress, this, &bStopBackup, 0);
                                                                               ^
```

[image]

Full Code Example:

```
 class BackupManager : public QObject {
     Q_OBJECT

 private:
 QWaitCondition pauseThreadCondition;
 QMutex backupPauseLock;
 bool bPauseBackup = false, bStopBackup = false;

 static DWORD CALLBACK copyProgress(
      LARGE_INTEGER totalSize, LARGE_INTEGER totalTransferred,
      LARGE_INTEGER streamSize, LARGE_INTEGER streamTransferred,
      DWORD streamNo, DWORD callbackReason, HANDLE src, HANDLE dst,
      LPVOID data);

     void copyFile(QString m_src, QString m_dst);

  //...

  signals:
     void fileCopyFinished();
     void fileCopyFailed(QString error);
     void fileCopyProgress(qint64 progress, qint64 total);
  //...
}
```

**and source**

```
void BackupManager::copyFile(QString m_src, QString m_dst)
{
     auto rc = CopyFileExW((LPCWSTR)m_src.utf16(), (LPCWSTR)m_dst.utf16(),
                           &BackupManager::copyProgress, this, &bStopBackup, 0);
     if (!rc)
          emit fileCopyFailed(getLastErrorMsg());
     emit fileCopyFinished();
}
DWORD CALLBACK BackupManager::copyProgress(
     const LARGE_INTEGER totalSize, const LARGE_INTEGER totalTransferred,
     LARGE_INTEGER, LARGE_INTEGER, DWORD,
     DWORD, HANDLE, HANDLE,
     LPVOID data)
{
//     emit fileCopyProgress(totalTransferred.QuadPart, totalSize.QuadPart);
//     if (bPauseBackup) {
//          backupPauseLock.lock();
//          pauseThreadCondition.wait(&backupPauseLock);
//          backupPauseLock.unlock();
//     }
     return PROGRESS_CONTINUE;
}
```

Taking a look at the error, it appears to require an int type (for the `LPBOOL`). Is it possible for me to use a bool in any way?

---

**UPDATE 2**

A quick search helped me with this using the `BOOL` datatype for `bStopBackup` which can be found in `minwindef.h`.

It compiles now

Comment: of course callback must be static member. and unclear what errors you got when/if you make it static

Comment: @RbMm hmm, I searched for the "static" keyword on the LPROUTINE & CopyFileExW page, but didn't find anything. How do you know it should be static? Also, see update

Comment: because any callback must exactly match signature. not static member not mach. so only static can be of course. for this not need any documentation

Comment: and are you understand different between *bool* and *BOOL* - compiler say you all. not understand in what problem

Comment: `BOOL bStopBackup = false;` must be

Comment: @RbMm thank you for the help, much appreciated!

Comment: Instead of _Update 2_, post an answer to your question.