# FileCopyExW reports last error as ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED - what does this mean in terms of FileCopyExW

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, file-copying, lpcwstr

**Context:**

I need to scan for, gather information and copy some media files from specific directories.

I have been having quite some trouble with some files not being detected, etc

**Problem:**

> **Warning to reader:** As seen on the screenshot and noted in a comment,
> the title and premise of this question are possible moot, as the error
> was more likely to be dec 32 (== 0x20) == ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION,
> which has an "easy" explantion in the answer to this question.

In the code below, I use a c-style cast to convert my `QString` into a `LPCWSTR` for the `CopyFileExW` which I found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19150462/4628115) SO post. I have tried many different conversions, but non of them seems to work correctly *- which for now is besides the point*.

The problem this 'conversion' technique gives is the error [ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-#ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED)

> ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED
>
> 50 (0x32)
>
> The request is not supported.

Frankly, this makes absolutely no sense to me in this context. I am copying from NTFS -> NTFS (same hard drive for testing), with destination file length < 200 characters (see image, 192 to be exact).

**The core code: (see bottom for full details)**

```
     // QString src (src file location), dst (destination file location)

     LPCWSTR localC_src = (LPCWSTR) src.utf16();
     LPCWSTR localC_dst = (LPCWSTR) dst.utf16();
     LPCWSTR dirC = (LPCWSTR) dir.utf16();

     auto rc = CopyFileExW(localC_src, localC_dst, &BackupManager::copyProgress, this, &bStopBackup, 0);
     if (rc == 0) {

          DWORD lastError = GetLastError(); // Error = 0x32
          bool dirExist = DirExists(dirC); // true
          bool fileExists = FileExists(localC_src); // true

          printWarning(TAG, QString("File Copy Error: %1").arg(getLastErrorMsg()));
#ifdef QT_DEBUG
          if (FileExists(localC_src)) {
               qDebug() << "#FailedCopy: Windows file exists but copy failed" << src;  // this gets hit using the implemented c-style cast 
          }
          else {
               if (QFile::exists(src)) {
                    qDebug() << "#FailedCopy: Windows is really being full of shit! " << src;   // this always gets triggered when using QString::toStdWString.c_str()
               }
               else {
                    qDebug() << "#FailedCopy: Windows file copy failed outright" << src; 
               }
          }
          // ...
    } else {
          // success
    }
```

What does this error mean in the `FileCopyExW` context?

*(also, if anyone has the source for windows.h implementation to allow me to trace the error further, please post it as a comment)*

**Image of debugger, etc**
[image]

**Full Code Implemenation:**

```
static QString toString(HRESULT hr)
{
     _com_error err{hr};
     const TCHAR* lastError = err.ErrorMessage();
     return QStringLiteral("Error 0x%1: %2").arg((quint32)hr, 8, 16, QLatin1Char('0'))
            .arg(lastError);
}

static QString getLastErrorMsg()
{
     DWORD lastError = GetLastError();
     QString s = toString(HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(lastError));
     return s;
}

BOOL FileExists(LPCWSTR szPath)
{
     DWORD dwAttrib = GetFileAttributes(szPath);

     return (dwAttrib != INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES &&
             !(dwAttrib & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY));
}

// not used
static const wchar_t* toLPCWSTR(QString s)
{
     std::wstring dstWString = s.toStdWString();
     const wchar_t* localC_src = dstWString.c_str();
     return localC_src;
}

static bool DirExists(LPCWSTR szPath)
{
     DWORD ftyp = GetFileAttributes(szPath);
     if (ftyp == INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES)
          return false;  //something is wrong with your path!

     if (ftyp & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
          return true;   // this is a directory!

     return false;    // this is not a directory!
}

BackupResult BackupManager::copyFile(QString m_src, QString m_dst)
{
     QFileInfo fi(m_src);
     QString dir = fi.dir().path();
//     const wchar_t* dirC = toLPCWSTR(dir);
     QString src = QString(m_src).replace("/", "\\");
     QString dst = QString(m_src).replace("/", "\\");
//     const wchar_t* localC_src = toLPCWSTR(src);
//     const wchar_t* localC_dst = toLPCWSTR(dst);
     LPCWSTR localC_src = (LPCWSTR) src.utf16();
     LPCWSTR localC_dst = (LPCWSTR) dst.utf16();
     LPCWSTR dirC = (LPCWSTR) dir.utf16();

     auto rc = CopyFileExW(localC_src, localC_dst, &BackupManager::copyProgress, this, &bStopBackup, 0);
     if (rc == 0) {

          DWORD lastError = GetLastError(); // Error = 0x32
          bool dirExist = DirExists(dirC); // true
          bool fileExists = FileExists(localC_src); // true

          printWarning(TAG, QString("File Copy Error: %1").arg(getLastErrorMsg()));
#ifdef QT_DEBUG
          if (FileExists(localC_src)) {
               qDebug() << "#FailedCopy: Windows file exists but copy failed" << src; // this gets hit using the implemented c-style cast 
          }
          else {
               if (QFile::exists(src)) {
                    qDebug() << "#FailedCopy: Windows is really being full of shit! " << src;   // this always gets triggered when using QString::toStdWString.c_str()
               }
               else {
                    qDebug() << "#FailedCopy: Windows file copy failed outright" << src;
               }
          }
#endif
          // copy failed
          return BackupResult::IOError;
     }

     // copy success
     return BackupResult::Success;
}
```

Comment: In your screenshot it looks like the error code is '32' = ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION, not '0x32' = ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you check whether the copied file handle is opened in another process.

I created a simple sample, the code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    CopyFileEx(L"D:\\test\\test.txt", L"D:\\test\\test2.txt", NULL, NULL, 0, 0);
    int e = GetLastError();
    cout << "error code is :" << e << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This sample of course successfully copied the file.But if I add the code to open the handle of this file, it will return error code 32.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    CreateFileW(L"D:\\test\\test.txt", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);
    CopyFileEx(L"D:\\test\\test.txt", L"D:\\test\\test2.txt", NULL, NULL, 0, 0);
    int e = GetLastError();
    cout << "error code is :" << e << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Outout:
[image]

So I think you did not close it properly after opening the handle in other locations. If you need to copy files while the handle is open, you can modify the `dwShareMode` parameter to `FILE_SHARE_READ`. In this way, the file copy operation can be performed when the handle is opened.

Here is the sample:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    CreateFileW(L"D:\\test\\test.txt", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);
    CopyFileEx(L"D:\\test\\test.txt", L"D:\\test\\test2.txt", NULL, NULL, 0, 0);
    int e = GetLastError();
    cout << "error code is :" << e << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

[image]

More reference:[`CreateFileW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew) and [`CopyFileExA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-copyfileexa)

Comment: `FILE_SHARE_READ` may or may not produce a sharing violation. That solely depends on the desired access, the desired access of the already opened file handles as well as their share mode.

Comment: Hi,if this answer did help to you, please feel free to mark it to help people with the same issue, and let me know if you have any problem.Thanks.